# How to query struct type in bigquery without "Field name step does not exist in STRUCT"?

Tags: sql, struct, google-bigquery

When I run this query in bigquery

```
select jsonpayload.context.input.step
from `table_2019*`
```

respond is

> "Field name step does not exist in STRUCT at [1:34]"

However, When running the same query on other tables like table_20190101 or table_20190102 it worked fine

How can I fix my code to show all results without an error or ignore error thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I fix my code to show all results without an error?
>   The problem is not in your SQL code

You are running a query on an old partition which means the physical structure of each partition can be different. Based on the error message at least 1 of those partitions doesn't have the field *step* while the other does.

**Option 1**
The simplest way to find this is to use the webUI the review partition structure and find the gap

[image]

**Option 2**

If you are subscribed to [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables) beta feature you can run this query to understand where the problem is:

```
select * from `datasetId.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
where table_name like 'table%'
limit 100;
```

[image]

Regardless you can use [unnset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest) function to select from your *STRUCT* field, for example:

```
WITH `table` AS (
SELECT (ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y STRING>>[(1, 'foo'), (3, 'bar')]) as arr
)

select x, y from (
  select * from `table`, unnest(arr)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Tamir Klein thank you very much for your answer.Actually i already know where problem. my problem happen because in my application not have event in this field today but i need to know how to run SQL to ignore this case.Because i need to track event every 1 hour in my schedule.

Comment: Have you tried to use `unnest` as described in this link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest

Comment: Thank you Tamir Klein i'll try your advice.

Comment: Sure, I update my answer to help you some more. Please consider accepting the answer and voting up if this was helpful to you, see how in this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Comment: Sorry it not work i try to run query for get this column(jsonpayload.context.input.step) but event in this partition not happen that mean in this partition not have this column but i try to select all (from `table_2019*`) but have error in this partition. If send me null it ok but send me error.

Comment: To be clear, Since you are using old partition with a mismatch in the structure you can't use * or other wild cards. So you will either use union which can become very long or make sure your structure is the same across all partitions. BTW: Can you move to new partition? It's much faster and better

Comment: Yes in partition table i need to union all table or create all partition table as 1 table by use sub query like ```select * from `table_2019*` ``` i try both and then start run but still not working and can you explain "move to new partition" ? i need to do this because i need all table to feed to data studio for create dashboard and calculate avg etc.

Comment: See this link on how to use new partition https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#creating_a_partitioned_table_from_a_query_result. Looks like you will need to build a migration process. Good luck.